# vb.net как посчитать сумму из двух string

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic

Имеется два `String`

```
Dim l_Number_1 As String = "5,5"
Dim l_Number_2 As String = "4,5"
```

Как посчитать оба `String` и получить 10?

Поиск результат не дал. Так же пробовал `string.Sum()` - но не понял как он работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из справки:

> В языке `VB.NET` применяются следующие методы для преобразований типов:
>   ...
>
> Метод **`CDbl`** преобразует в `Double` любой числовой тип (включая
>   `Byte`, `SByte` и типы перечисления), а также `Boolean`, `String`,
>   `Object`

```
dSumm = CDbl(l_Number_1) + CDbl(l_Number_2)
```